# Problems logging into Twitter using Twitter OAuth (PHP)

Tags: php, api, twitter, oauth

Alright, I am trying to do a very simple login script using the Twitter API.  All I need is a simple way for users to log into the site via Twitter.  I have a button on my homepage that says "Log in or register with Twitter", if they are not currently logged in.  If they ARE logged in, I want it to show their username with their avatar.  So here's what I have so far, and it's not working.

On the homepage (index.php), I have the following:

```
 <?php
      require_once 'lib/twitteroauth/OAuth.php';
      require_once 'lib/twitteroauth/twitteroauth.php';
      require_once 'config/config.php';
      session_start();
 ?>
```

config.php contains the following code (with consumer key & consumer secret obviously replaced):

```
 <?php
      $consumer_key = 'consumer key';
      $consumer_secret = 'consumer secret';
 ?>
```

and then later down the page, I also have the following, which displays either the log in/register message, or the username/avatar, depending on their login status.

```
 <?php
      if (!empty($_SESSION['request_token']) && !empty($_SESSION['request_token_secret'])) {
           $twitterOAuth = new TwitterOAuth($consumer_key, $consumer_secret, $_SESSION['request_token'], $_SESSION['request_token_secret']);
           $user = $twitterOAuth->get('account/verify_credentials');

           echo "Welcome ".$user->screen_name;
           echo "<img src='".$user->profile_image_url."'/>";
      } else {
           echo "<a href='twitter_login.php'>Sign In / Register With Twitter</a>";
           echo "<img src='images/twitter-banner.png'/>";
      }
 ?>
```

So that's the index.php page.  As you can see, if they are not logged in, and they click on the "Sign in" link, it will take them to another page, which is twitter_login.php.  The contents of that file are as follows:

```
 <?php
      require_once 'lib/twitteroauth/OAuth.php';
      require_once 'lib/twitteroauth/twitteroauth.php';
      require_once 'config/config.php';

      session_start();

      $twitterOAuth = new TwitterOAuth($consumer_key, $consumer_secret);

      $requestToken = $twitterOAuth->getRequestToken();

      $_SESSION['request_token'] = $requestToken['oauth_token'];
      $_SESSION['request_token_secret'] = $requestToken['oauth_token_secret'];

      header ('Location: '.$twitterOAuth->getAuthorizeURL($requestToken));
 ?>
```

This page will automatically redirect the user to Twitters Authorization URL.  The callback URL set in twitter is "authenticate.php".  The contents of that file are:

```
 <?php
      require_once 'lib/twitteroauth/OAuth.php';
      require_once 'lib/twitteroauth/twitteroauth.php';
      require_once 'config/config.php';

      session_start();

      if ($_SESSION['request_token'] == $_GET['oauth_token']) {
           $twitterOAuth = new TwitterOAuth($consumer_key, $consumer_secret, $_SESSION['request_token'], $_SESSION['request_token_secret']);

           $accessToken = $twitterOAuth->getAccessToken();

           if (isset($accessToken['user_id']) && is_numeric($accessToken['user_id'])) {
                $_SESSION['request_token'] = $accessToken['oauth_token'];
                $_SESSION['request_token_secret'] = $accessToken['oauth_token_secret'];
                header('Location: index.php');
           } else {
                echo "Something went wrong.";
           }
      } else {
           echo "OAuth Tokens Do Not Match.";
      }
 ?>
```

Upon a successful log in, the user should be redirected back to index.php, and the homepage should then show their username/avatar.  In my own testing, I've found that it works fine when I try it in Firefox, but when I try it in any other browser (Safari/Chrome), it seems to get stuck at the twitter authorization.  Any idea what I am doing wrong, or what I can do to improve/fix this script?  I'm at my wits end trying to figure this out.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Bump?  Anybody?  Bueller?  Bueller?

Answer (score 0):

I think your callback url is breaking. You can check it with any kind of tool or browser debugger to find out what's happening to the url being authenticated.

Comment: What precisely am I looking for?  When I get to the authenticate page, it returns the error "OAuth Tokens Do Not Match."  If you would like to check the script out for yourself, you can go to the following URL:  http://www.fontastiq.com and click on the "Sign-In With Twitter" button at the top.

Comment: Just now I my twitter account authorized without any problems. I used Chrome. On looking at the console I got a couple of 404 errors.     GET http://www.fontastiq.com/js/globalActions.js 404 (Not Found) index.php:10
GET http://www.fontastiq.com/images/facebook.png 404 (Not Found) index.php:131
GET http://www.fontastiq.com/images/twitter.png 404 (Not Found) index.php:132
GET http://www.fontastiq.com/images/pinterest.png 404 (Not Found)